# How to model the distribution over payouts from aggregate (sum) data?

Tags: distributions, latent-variable, aggregation

#### The setting

A user is presented with a number of options related to her search query. She chooses one of them. As a result, a payout is generated. The payout lies in the range [0.05, 0.50], but the payout of each option is not known. The total number of options is $n$.

#### Observable data

For each day, only aggregate data can be observed. Let $t$ be the time index, then we observe:

- $u_t$ the number of user on day $t$, and
- $q_t$ the total payout on day $t$ (sum of all payouts).

#### What I want to model

From the past time series, I want to estimate the distribution over payouts for a single user at time point $t + 1$. That is, from past *aggregate* data I would like to estimate the distribution reflecting *the payout generated by a single user*.

#### Questions

- What is a suitable model for this distribution? How can I estimate its parameters?
- Since the distribution over payouts may change over time, I would probably like to use past data in a weighted fashion. How can that be incorporated in the parameter estimation?

#### Example data

I can't post a histogram (because I don't have enough reputation points), so I'm describing the data here. I plotted a histogram of $q_t/u_t$ (average payout per user) over the last 100 days, to get a feel for the distribution:

- The payouts are dispersed around the mean (0.20)
- More dispersed than a normal distribution
- Slightly asymmetrical, the left tail is fatter than the right one

#### Possible approaches

One option is to think of the total payout as the sum of i.i.d. categorical random variables, see:

[Estimating parameters of categorical distribution from sum-of-outcome data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64228/estimating-parameters-of-categorical-distribution-from-sum-of-outcome-data)

Comment: What does "more dispersed than a normal distribution" mean?